# How to get data from notepad text file and create a collection of Java objects?

Tags: java, object, collections, text-files

I have a notepad file that contains the customers' data, 
**each line has a new customer:**

All I want to get the data from the notepad file (as below) and save each customer in a java object and save each object in a list of customers.

```
Print_Sequence|Indication|SP/N-SP    |Bill_Type  |Region|Cluster
00001         |Ordinary  |           |Notice Bill|      | C10
00002         |Ordinary  |           |Notice Bill|      | C20
00003         |Ordinary  |           |Notice Bill|      | C30
```

I got the data from the file in a string variable:

```
String details = "";
KE_Globals.dataFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile();
Scanner input = new Scanner(KE_Globals.dataFile);

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    details += input.nextLine()+System.getProperty("line.separator");
}
```

Now, I want to convert the data into this Java Class: **Customer**:

```
public class Customer {

private String Print_Sequence = null;
private String Indication = null;
private String SPN_SP = null;
private String Bill_Type = null;
private String Region = null;
private String Cluster = null;

public Customer(String print_Sequence, String indication, String sPN_SP, String bill_Type, String region, String cluster) {
    Print_Sequence = print_Sequence;
    Indication = indication;
    SPN_SP = sPN_SP;
    Bill_Type = bill_Type;
    Region = region;
    Cluster = cluster;
}

public String getPrint_Sequence() {
    return Print_Sequence;
}

public void setPrint_Sequence(String print_Sequence) {
    Print_Sequence = print_Sequence;
}

public String getIndication() {
    return Indication;
}

public void setIndication(String indication) {
    Indication = indication;
}

public String getSPN_SP() {
    return SPN_SP;
}

public void setSPN_SP(String sPN_SP) {
    SPN_SP = sPN_SP;
}

public String getBill_Type() {
    return Bill_Type;
}

public void setBill_Type(String bill_Type) {
    Bill_Type = bill_Type;
}

public String getRegion() {
    return Region;
}

public void setRegion(String region) {
    Region = region;
}

public String getCluster() {
    return Cluster;
}

public void setCluster(String cluster) {
    Cluster = cluster;
}

}
```

> Can anybody please tell me how do I do this? like:

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
Customer c = new Customer();
c.setProperties....

customers.add( c );
```

Thank you.

Comment: OP: Don't create getters & setters automatically - do you need them? Nope, you don't. Pass all the parameters needed through the constructor(s).

Comment: @Nikolas I have total of 408 fields and the maximum number of parameters is 255. I guess we can't pass all the parameters. Please suggest

Comment: You should have no more than 5 fields in an object (those numbers vary but are that small). 408 is absolutéy insane and the design is terrible. Decompose objects to the smaller ones. Please forgot to think like this and read some books or articles about object oriented design first. What you do is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can do it: iterate through all the lines in the file and parse a `Customer` from each line, where the parsing involves splitting the line into fields separated by `|` and stripping the whitespace.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
    KE_Globals.dataFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile();
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(KE_Globals.dataFile);
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String customerRecord = input.nextLine();
        customers.add(Customer.parseFromRecord(customerRecord));
    }
}
```

---

```
class Customer {
    private String printSequence = null;
    private String indication = null;
    // ... more fields

    // probably don't want this part of the class interface
    private Customer() {}

    static Customer parseFromRecord(String recordLine) {
        // splits the string while removing extra whitespace
        String[] fields = recordLine.split("\\s*\\|\\s*");
        if(fields.length != 408) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Customer record '" + recordLine + "' is invalid.");
        }

        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.printSequence = fields[0];
        c.indication = fields[1];
        // ... for each field

        return cust;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have total of 408 fields, so the problem is we can't pass constructor arguments more than 255. Then? please suggest

Comment: In that case you could pass the array itself as an argument, then load the fields from it. Or possibly just set them with setters. See edits.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the `00001         |Ordinary  |           |Notice Bill|      | C10` customer record from file, then split the line based on `|` pipe

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
String customeRecord = input.nextLine().split("[|]");  //or  \\|

Customer record = new Customer(customeRecord[0],customeRecord[1],customeRecord[2],customeRecord[3],customeRecord[4],customeRecord[5]);

 //finally add this customer object to List
  customers.add(record);
}
```

**Note :** when you split the string `00001         |Ordinary  |           |Notice Bill|      | C10` based on pipe `|` each part will be with some white spaces, you need to trim whitespaces to get accurate value, and if first line is headers you need to ignore that also

Comment: I have total of 408 fields, so the problem is we can't pass constructor arguments more than 255. Then? please suggest

Comment: first having 400+ fields in class is not good approach, second if there is no other way then use setters and getters to inject field values into object. @BadshahTracker

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems like you already know how to read the lines from the file, so I'm going to assume that you're able to do this.

Let's say you have some line of the file; since they're all of the same formatting, that makes this task much easier.

Let's say:
    String s = input.nextLine();

Then, using String#split("|"), we can easily parse the different parts of this String into those that we want. Let's say we have the line:

```
"00001         |Ordinary  |           |Notice Bill|      | C10"
```

Then, if this is the input that we received by doing input.nextLine(), we can call s.split("|"), which will give us an array of the following strings:

```
String[] array = {"00001         ","Ordinary  ","           ","Notice Bill","      "," C10"};
```

String also has a nice method called String#trim(), that will remove any leading whitespace and any ending whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc).

So, for each string in the array, we can trim the input, which will give us this:

```
So now, we have that array = {"00001","Ordinary","","Notice Bill","","C10"}.
```

Now we have something that we can easily work with. Assuming the same order is held (which it is), we can say:

```
Customer c = new Customer(array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5]);
```

Combining all of this, we can do the following (taking the excerpt from your code):

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String nextInput = input.nextLine();
    String[] pI = nextInput.split("\\|"); //pI stands for parseableInput, escape the pipe character ('|') since it's a special char in Java.
    for(int i = 0; i < nextInput.length; i++) { //trim all of the input
        pI[i] = pI[i].trim();
    }
    Customer next = new Customer(pI[0], pI[1], pI[2], pI[3], pI[4], pI[5]);
    customers.add(next);
}
```

I wrote this in a more verbose way in order to make it easily readable. This should work for every line because they're of the same style each time. If you want, you could also make empty strings be represented as 'null' for the Customer, which might help to clean up the code.

Hope this helped.

Edit: Added quotations to strings for clarity.

Comment: I have total of 408 fields, so the problem is we can't pass constructor arguments more than 255. Then? please suggest

Comment: What do you mean by this? Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: just like you passed 6 arguments to the constructor `Customer c = new Customer(array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5]);` so, we cannot pass more than 255 arguments but I have 408 fields to pass.

Comment: I can't imagine that there's a purpose for a constructor with 408 different arguments, but if that's the case, you could create a new customer, without passing in any fields, then have 2 (very large) setter methods, both with 204 methods, though that's incredibly, incredibly excessive, and I urge you to reconsider the necessity of doing that.

Comment: If you're saying the file itself has 408 fields, that's easy to parse and can be done with the exact method above and just be passed into an array of Strings that you could pass directly into the constructor very easily, which is probably the better method here.

Answer (score 1):

Check this way

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
String [] arr = new String[6];

   while (input.hasNextLine()) {                   
    arr =  input.nextLine().split("\\|");
    Customer customer = new Customer(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]arr[4],arr[5])
    customers.add(customer);

}
```

you can iterate the list to see

```
for(Customer c: customers){
    System.out.println(c.toString());
}
```

> Important to mention '|' is a especial character in java you need to put this "\\|" to recognize it'

Comment: I have total of 408 fields, so the problem is we can't pass constructor arguments more than 255. Then? please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the customer data from the text file and populate to a `List` collection:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class CustomerExtraction {

    public static void main(String [] args)
            throws IOException {

        Path file = Paths.get("customer_data.txt");
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file);
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            String [] fields = lines.get(i).split("\\|");
            Customer cust = new Customer(fields[0].trim(), fields[1].trim(), fields[2].trim(), fields[3].trim(), fields[4].trim(), fields[5].trim());
            System.out.println(cust); // print to console for verification
            customers.add(cust);
        }
    }
}

class Customer {

    private String printSequence;
    private String indication;
    private String spnSp;
    private String billType;
    private String region;
    private String cluster;

    public Customer(String printSequence, String indication, String spnSp, String billType, String region, String cluster) {
        this.printSequence = printSequence;
        this.indication = indication;
        this.spnSp = spnSp;
        this.billType = billType;
        this.region = region;
        this.cluster = cluster;
    }

    // get and set methods as required here ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.join(", ", printSequence, indication, spnSp, billType, region, cluster);
    }
}
```

Notes about the code in `CustomerExtraction.java`:

The following statement reads the input customer data text file and stores in a `List<String>` collection. Each line in the file is an element in the list (e.g.: "00001         |Ordinary  |           |Notice Bill|      | C10").

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file);
```

This iterates all the lines in the list (excluding the first line, which is the column headers).

```
for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {
```

This splits each customer line into tokens (fields) resulting a `String` array.

```
String [] fields = lines.get(i).split("\\|");
```

The later code is to create the `Customer` object from the `String` fields in the string array. The `String` class's `trim()` method removes the spaces at the beginning and end of each field. Then, add each customer to the `List<Customer>` collection.

Notes about `Customer` class:

- No need to initialize to instance variable `String`s to `null`; by default they are `null`.
- The variable names need to be *camelCase* (not starting with uppercase) and no underscores.
- The variable SPN_SP: it is convention    that only constants (static and final fields) are represented in all uppercase.

Comment: I have total of 408 fields, so the problem is we can't pass constructor arguments more than 255. Then? please suggest

Comment: I think you can convert the text file to CSV (Comma Seperated Values) format file. This means each line's separator ("|") has to be replaced with a comma (","). Then there are utility programs (libraries) to convert CSV to Java objects. I suggest, you do some searching the net (Google) using a search-string like _"Java CSV to object"_.